How to go from Asia to America by ferry
Is it any ferry from south Asia to South America?
I want travel from Busan (Korea) to Indonesia, Philippines, Thailand, Malaysia and then to South America by ferry or any ship (yachts, freight liners).

Are you aware that the shortest distance between Malaysia and South America (mainland) is over 19000 km? That's one of the longest trips you can do on the planet (which tops out at 20000km between antipodes).  That's more than 3 weeks at average cruise ship speeds (without any stops).

@Hilmar the shortest distance between Malaysia and South America (mainland) is over 19000 km - Not if you go the other direction, south of Africa

@Midavalo I've seen stories that due to increased pirate activity in the northern indian ocean that private yachts are choosing not to travel in that direction. So while it may be shorter, it may not be the safest thing to do

Surely the shortest distance as described by the title is across the Bering Strait. Sadly, there aren't any regular passenger ferries.

Is buying / renting a yacht an option? Otherwise your outlook is pretty bleak.

@Johnnyjanko, unless they have experience sailing cross ocean in not safe. So next to buying that yacht they will have to find, and likely pay, experienced crew.

You’re going the wrong way. If you start from Malaysia and go north you’re already getting closer to North America. Hokkaido isn’t very far from Alaska.

Alas, this is virtually impossible if you want to go direct from Asia to South America, and very expensive even if you detour via North America.

There are no passenger ferry services between Asia and anywhere in the Americas (North or South).

There are some seasonal repositioning cruises between the two continents, but these involve weeks on a luxurious cruise ship and are priced accordingly, plus virtually all terminate in North America (typically Alaska or Vancouver).

This leaves cargo/freighter services that take passengers, but these were always quite limited and intercontinental services in particular have become virtually extinct since COVID.

Yachts are, theoretically, an option, but in addition to the considerable challenge of finding somebody willing to give a useless landlubber a lift halfway around the world, due to prevailing winds almost all popular routes go westwards from the Americas to Asia, which is the wrong direction for you.



" which is the wrong direction for you." --> OP did not mention direction, just start/end.  Maybe go west.

Back a few centuries ago there was robust trade between Manila and Mexico for almost 300 years, and I'm pretty sure that was with sailing ships /s

Best sailing direction changes with the seasons, but some are easier than others.

(+1) @PeterM The route they used does not go to South America, the equivalent in the southern hemisphere is more-or-less the first described route in the link. The Vendée Globe is sailed eastwards during the southern hemisphere's summer. Competitive round-the-world sailors go even further south than the Manila galleon went north but that's the same idea, you need to go to higher latitudes to find the westerlies. That's presumably why lambshaanxy wrote almost but in practice you also need a route that's popular and not too unpleasant to find a ship willing to take you.

Freighter trips are still alive, I even did one last year! But you're right, nothing intercontinental, almost all that can be booked are in Europe, sadly, I see your link already explains this…

@Relaxed The link I provided shows dates trade going as far south as Lima. I may be wrong, but I assumed that Lima was in South America.

@Peter Yes, from Mexico, not straight from Manila. The point is not that you cannot reach the southern hemisphere or sail eastwards further south. I already mentioned the Vendée globe but the Portuguese famously sailed from Brazil to the southern tip of Africa. The point is that you don't want to cross the ocean directly from Manila to Lima and the Spanish galleons used the northern route to do that.

If you really want to find some historical counter-example then the Polynesian navigation would be the best one but the fact remains that the most dependable way to go east is to first go north (or south), which is why most leisure craft prefer to go westwards at nicer latitudes. That's all the answer is explaining.

I'm not sure yachts are a viable options. Most of them are not certified for ocean crossing, (designed for holidays, in fact there are various "transported ships" which move yachts between oceans). -- Also cruise ships are not in general luxurious (in fact they can be a cheap holiday). There are few other cruise ships (around world tour, which are more on expensive side), and now various expedition cruises. -- In any case I think your answer is the maximum we can give, for more, the OP should do many long searches on Internet.

Agreed with Giacomo that cruise ships are often designed for cheap vacations. This tends to be even more true on repositioning cruises, as the number of people willing to pay $$$ to spend weeks at sea with few, if any, interesting stops is quite small. That said, I'm not sure how often repositioning cruises between Asia and the Americas actually happen, especially if you're ruling out a stop in North America.

As for the sailing direction, that only applies to literal sailing, with a sail. Wind direction doesn't matter as much to most modern ocean-going vessels, which are powered by engines rather than sails.

It is rather difficult as explained by the other answer. It is possible though to do the passage by sea on cruises. This would be an expensive trip but I think it should be mentioned for completeness.
To make the journey, you would need two cruises to reach North America or Central America and one to go to South America. There are several ways to do the journey, depending on time and money:

Starting in Indonesia, you can book a cruise from Bali to Sidney which are not so expensive, about $7500 USD for the 16-day trip. Usually there are several stops along the northern coast of Australia and some in Indonesia, including Komodo. Then you take one shorter cruise from Sidney to Auckland, followed by the expensive part of the journey which is Auckland to Los Angeles. This 32-day cruise starts at $15,000 USD. At that point you have reached the Americas!  Getting to South America from there is comparatively inexpensive, count $2000 but some are advertised for less, depending on the destination and service.

Starting from Bali in Indonesia, there are cruises that will take you all the way to Auckland. Those are more expensive but will have you some journey and days while waiting for the cruises to synchronize. In fact, there is a 50-day trip from Auckland to Cartagena (Colombia) starting in November which is sold out for this year already.

Now if you are willing to start the trip in Northern Asia instead, there is a direct route from there to North America which is significantly less expensive that previous options. Going from Tokyo to Vancouver takes a 20-day cruise with price starting at $8500 USD. Of course, reaching South America from there requires longer cruises but those are not uncommon and less expensive.


Another route to explore is through the South Pacific since that would get you to South America without going to North America at all. There are many cruises from French Polynesia to South or Central America. For about $12,000 you can reach Chile and more expensive options can take you to Colombia. The one missing segment, I haven't figured out quite yet. You still would have to get to Australia as I've only found cruises to Papeete from Darwin which would require you to get off early from the Bali to Sidney cruise. There is probably a Sidney to Papeete cruise but so far I only found the trip advertised in the other direction.

Of course, if you're going the Northern route instead, you can probably do it a lot cheaper. Go by land or air to Provideniya and get a boat to cross the Bering Straight to, say, Nome. Congratulations, you're in the Americas! Make sure to check in with CBP, though, as they might be a little skeptical of random boats crossing the straight from Russia. It's only about 230 miles between those cities. Of course, the straight is as narrow as 50 miles in places, but there aren't legal ports to cross there, as far as I know.

As the other answers indicate, this is not realistic as a passenger.
Do you have any experience at sea? No? The plan you have laid out is not good. To put this into perspective, it makes more sense to sail to Antarctica and fly to south America. Antarctica.
The only way to make this trip resemble the plan you laid out is to make two legs. One leg of travel is Busan to Malaysia (the number one location on Earth for piracy). The second leg is south America.
If you have no experience at sea, you should not sail from Malaysia to south America under any conceivable circumstance.
The "realistic way" an offshore sailor would make this trip is in reverse, South America to fiji(?)/australia then to malaysia, etc. This would be an extreme outlier for a journey.

OP is asking about ferries, not sailing by himself.

"ferry or any ship (yachts"

I am offshore yachtsman referring directly to being a mariner and the importance of having experience.
